# Why can't visual studio and javascript find id for Html.EnumDropDownListFor?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, razor

I have a enumdropdownlistfor in my html like this.

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Status, new { @class = "btn btn-default btn-lg dropdown-toggle", id = "enumstatus" })
```

it has an id of enumstatus. I'm trying to get visual studio to recognize it but 
there is a constant blue line under the 'enumstatus' name.

[image: blue line]

When I run the application it seems to pull the value correctly, it just keeps the blue line there saying it "cannot resolve the id enumstatus".

Comment: visual studio cannot recognize html that is not there yet.
the moment you write that javascript there is no such element with the given id.

Comment: if I use an html tag instead of a razor tag on other elements it recognizes it! ex. I was having the same problem with html.editorfor and I replaced it with an html input tag with type="text" and now it recognizes it.

Answer (score 1):

`enumstatus` is something you are providing at razor level.

Now, there are steps involved

1. When you run the project as razor is just view engine and it will not be recognized by any browser. Hence your cshtml code will be converted to html and C#  code by razor view engine.
2. All the html controls like id will be resolved only at run time and will be assigned to particular control.

As your razor do not understand anything `id="enumstatus"`. Hence your are getting that line "cannot resolve the id enumstatus".

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
var statusDroppdown = document.getElementById('StatusId');
```

`EnumDropDownListFor` as well as `DropDownListFor` and other helpers use your model field names to generate HTML elements names.